# How to have multiple windows in R

Tags: r

I'm using R on my university computer. When I plot something, the plot appears in the same window, on top of my console window.

Here's a screenshot of the problem (from Windows):

[image]

**How can I tell R to open the plot in a separate window?**

I cannot change any system files.

*System info:*

- R verson 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
- Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit))

Comment: This seems to be a problem of the gui you are using. So: What GUI are you using?

Comment: Can you use an alternative GUI (like ESS, Eclipse+StatET, Rstudio)?

Comment: I have to write an exam in this software. I cannot use a different one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at `?dev.new`:

```
plot(1:10)
dev.new()
plot(1:10)
```

*EDIT:* If you using the default Rgui you maybe want to select the SDI (Single Document Interface) layout. You have to go to `Edit->GUI preferences` and select `SDI` instead of `MDI`. Then hit `Save` and `OK` and restart your Rgui.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I don't want a second plot window. On my machine the console and the plot(s) are all inside the same parent window, instead of in separate windows.

Comment: @what: Indeed I didn't read carefully enough. Please see my edit.